# Editing user permissions or restoring SQLBuddy to default, for Wampserver?

Tags: wampserver, sqlbuddy

I accidentally locked myself out by creating a new user account (with what I thought had full privileges) and deleting root altogether instead of editing it.  I'm not the brightest bulb in the box sometimes.

Basically, how can I restore my full user privileges -- either by restoring everything to default or modifying my current configuration for SQLBuddy?

I've looked online and I'm having trouble finding an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, you are not having a good time recently are you.

- Stop the mysql service

  wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
- Edit the my.ini file

  wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
- Find the [wampmysqld] section in the ini file

  Add this line directly after the section [wampmysqld]

  skip-grant-tables
- Restart the mysql service.

  wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
- Open the MySQL console

  wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Console

  just hit enter when asked for the password.

Now we are going to give all privilages to your new account.

enter the following 2 commands at the `mysql>` command prompt, each with a semi colon at the end of a line, and press ENTER after each line to issue the command to mysql.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'Your_Userid'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

***Note*** If you created this new user with more than one domain i.e. xxx@localhost and xxx@127.0.0.1 you should do this for each domain

- Now enter 'quit' at the mysql command promt to exist mysql.
- Stop the mysql service

  wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Stop Service
- Edit the my.ini file

  wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
- Find the [wampmysqld] section in the ini file

  Remove the 'skip-grant-tables' parameter we added earlier.
  **DO NOT Leave this parameter in the ini file its a HUGH security hole.**
- Restart the mysql service.
  wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Start/Resume Service

You should now be able to login with phpmyadmin or SQLBuddy using your new useridand the new password you have just set for that user.